# "-i" argument can referenced in your program by "args.interface" and the "-p" argument can be referenced as "args.port"

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

How I make the following changes to the code: "-i" argument can referenced in your program by "args.interface" and the "-p" argument can be referenced as "args.port".Also, how do I add a argument for an Ip address that has a full word.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", help="Interface", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-p", help="Target Port", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Using Network Interface: %s" % args.i)
print("Target Port: %d" % args.p)
```

Comment: You can add a  long-flag as well.  `add_argument('-i', '--interface', help='....')`.  This and the `dest` parameter should be covered in the `argparse` docs.  How is the `ip` argument any different from the `-i` one?  Add a `print(args)` to your code during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

If you add the kwarg *dest* to your add_argument calls, you can specify a full descriptive name of the arguments as you want them to appear on the object returned by *parse_args()*

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-i", dest="interface", help="Interface", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-p", dest="port", help="Target Port", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Using Network Interface: %s" % args.interface)
print("Target Port: %d" % args.port)
```